# HP Proliant DL380 G7 Integrated Lights-Out crashing

Tags: hp-proliant

I have a failure in the panel of the HP ProLiant DL380 G7.

When turning on the server all the LED's are lit solid amber except for the power that is blinking and the NIC's all in green LED. The panel remains like this for some time and then it goes off completely.

The server is working fully in all aspects. I've even checked with SmartStart 8.70 if there was any hidden failure and the server passed all tests as can be seen in the link below.

The BIOS is now up to date with the latest version available.

I'm out of options! If anyone can give me a hint I will be very grateful!

[short video and pics](https://mega.nz/folder/DpsxCCzA#z1OlXlF1GP4Kboda2sDtcA)

Comment: Things you can try: 1)  remove all power cables for about 5 minutes. 2) if this doesn't help, try an [NVRAM reset](https://www.running-system.com/how-to-clear-or-reset-a-hp-server-gen9-nvram-using-system-maintenance-switch-on-the-system-board/) (the link is for a Gen9, but it's the same for Gen 10, Gen8, G7, G6 - can't remember older generations) 3) reseat the cable for the SID on the motherboard

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing a format of the NAND drive, also known as internal sd-card storage. It can can clear several weird iLO faults, and it probaly needs an update too. iLO is not updated as a part of a BIOS update.

Read carefully and understand that a cold boot is necessary :)

https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/product?language=en_US&tab=driversAndSoftware&kmpmoid=4091567&driversAndSoftwareFilter=8000029